# Bit Model Cost For Counting to N

Tags: algorithm, binary, time-complexity, addition, counting

Considering a computational model resembling that of schoolbook addition  where each operation cost 1 unit, what is the bit model cost for binary addition for counting to *n* where *n* is a power of two?

**MODEL**

The computational model is based on toy blocks that have 0 and 1 written on them. Initially, a zero block sits on a table (free). Each block operation (removing or adding a block ) costs 1 unit.

The objective is to replace the (binary) number on the table by 1, 2, 3, ..., n. This is done by imitating **add-with-carry**.

For example, we start with a 0. To count to 1, we need to remove the 0 (costs 1) and add a 1 (costs 1). Then, to count to 2, we need to add a 1 (costs 1). We then remove the two ones (costs 2), replace by a 0 (costs 1) and add a 1 (costs 1) in front to make 10 (base 2) (costs 1). And so on, until *n*.

I figured that when the least significant bit is 0, the cost is 2 (remove 0, add 1). When the lsb is 1, the cost is 5.

**Costs to increment a number**

```
0000 ->  0           (0 time unit to go to 0 - block already there)
0001 ->  2           (2 operations to go to 2)
0010 ->  1*4 + 1     (1 carry)
0011 ->  2
0100 ->  2*4 + 1     (2 carries)
0101 ->  2
0110 ->  5
0111 ->  2
1000 ->  3*4 + 1     (3 carries)
1001 ->  2
1010 ->  5
1011 ->  2
1100 ->  2*4 + 1
1101 ->  2
1110 ->  5
1111 ->  2
10000 ->  4*4 + 1
10001 ->  2
10010 ->  5
...
```

I start to see a pattern, but can't formalize it.

It looks like `T(n) = sum from k = 1 to log n of (4k +1) + 9 * 2^(log n - 2)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the cost of the operations you're describing. Can you describe what costs you're counting and how you're counting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think about this is to sum across the *columns* rather than the *rows*. Suppose you're counting up to 2<sup>k</sup>. Then:

- In all 2<sup>k</sup> operations, the 1's bit will flip.
- In 2<sup>k</sup> / 2 = 2<sup>k-1</sup> of those operations, the 2's bit will flip.
- In 2<sup>k</sup> / 4 = 2<sup>k-2</sup> of those operations, the 4's bit will flip.
- In 2<sup>k</sup> / 8 = 2<sup>k-3</sup> of those operations, the 8's bit will flip.
- ...
- In 2<sup>k</sup> / 2<sup>k</sup> = 1 of those operations, the 2<sup>k</sup>'s bit will flip.

(In the above, I'm counting adding a new 1 digit in as a "flip" rather than an "add" because you can think of it as either flipping from 0 to 1 or adding a new 1 digit to the front.)

This means that the total number of bits that have to change is given by

> 2<sup>k</sup> + 2<sup>k-1</sup> + 2<sup>k-2</sup> + ... + 1
>
> = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1

So there will be a total of 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1 bits flipped. We can check this: counting from 0 to 1, we get

```
0
1
```

So one bit is flipped (1 = 2<sup>1</sup> - 1, as we predicted). When counting from 0 to 2, we get

```
00
01
10
```

That's a total of three bit flips (0 -> 1 -> 0 in the 1's place and 0 -> 1 in the 2's place), and 3 = 2<sup>2</sup> - 1, as we guessed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does help indeed. I would just need to find a way to convert the "flips" to bit operations... hmm..

Comment: What about half of the flips cost 2 operations (go from 0->1) and the other half cost 4 (go from 1->0)? The answer would be 2^(k+1)+2^(k+2)-5.